# Python Text to Image Conversion

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a python program that can read text from an Excel file and convert the data of over 500k text records from its column B to images with a logo at the top left (I have the base image for this).

Below is the code I have written so far. I know I can use Pandas library to read CSV and excel. But not sure about the further steps:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os

def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text="Hello", size=12):
    
    "Draw a text on an Image, saves it, show it"
    fnt = font = ImageFont.load_default()

    # create image
    image = Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (200,70), color = "red")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    # draw text
    draw.text((10,10), text, font=fnt, fill=(255,255,0))
    
    # save file
    image.save(filename)
    
    # show file
    os.system(filename)
    text_on_img(text="This is my text", size=52)
```

Could anyone help me complete this further?

Comment: if you have function for single text then use `for`-loop to run it for every text from list or from `DataFrame`. And for `DataFrame` you may also use `.apply()`  to execute functio for every element in column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have function to do it for single word then use `for`-loop to repeate it for every word on list.

```
def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text='Hello', size=12):
    # only for test
    print(filename, text)


data = ['Hello', 'World', 'Python']

for word in data:
    text_on_img(text=word)
```

But it will use the same filename for every word so it may need to enumerate words to create uniqu filename

```
def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text='Hello', size=12):
    # only for test
    print(filename, text)


data = ['Hello', 'World', 'Python']

for number, word in enumerate(data, 1):
    name = f"{number:02}.png"    # two digits
    text_on_img(filename=name, text=word)
```

---

For `DataFrame` you can do similar with `iterrows()`

```
import pandas as pd

def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text='Hello', size=12):
    # only for test
    print(filename, text)
    

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'word': ['Hello', 'World', 'Python']
})    

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    name = f"{index+1:02}.png"    # two digits
    word = row['word']
    text_on_img(filename=name, text=word)
```

Or you can use `apply(function)` to execute `function(row)` on  every row in `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text='Hello', size=12):
    # only for test
    print(filename, text)
    

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'word': ['Hello', 'World', 'Python']
})    

def my_function(row):
    index = row.name
    name = f"{index+1:02}.png"    # two digits
    word = row['word']
    text_on_img(filename=name, text=word)
    
df.apply(my_function, axis=1)
```